# Detect Cut operation in textfield - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfielddelegate

I have implemented the `shouldChangeCharactersIn` textfield delegate method. I have formatted the value in textfield so that textfield string becomes a comma separated currency type value. For that, I am explicitly handling the cursor to support conditions like inserting 2 commas at a time. The code used is :

```
let textBeforeEditing = textField.text!
    if ((string == "0" || string == "") && (textField.text! as NSString).range(of: ".").location < range.location) {
        return true
    }
    var currentPosition = 0
    if let selectedRange = textField.selectedTextRange {
        currentPosition = textField.offset(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: string == "" ? selectedRange.end : selectedRange.start)
    }
    let allowedCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted
    let filtered = string.components(separatedBy: allowedCharacterSet)
    let component = filtered.joined(separator: "")
    let isNumeric = string.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "") == component
    var textFieldString : String = ""
    var numberWithoutCommas : String = ""
    guard isNumeric else {
        return false
    }
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    textFieldString = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    numberWithoutCommas = textFieldString.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
    let formattedNumberWithoutCommas = formatter.number(from: numberWithoutCommas)
    guard let formattedNumber = formattedNumberWithoutCommas, var formattedString = formatter.string(from: formattedNumber) else {
        textField.text = nil
        return false
    }
    if string == "." && range.location == textField.text?.count {
        formattedString = formattedString.appending(".")
    }
    var filteredRegex = [NSTextCheckingResult]()
    filteredRegex = Constant.Regex.decimalRegex.matches(in: formattedString, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, formattedString.count))
    guard filteredRegex.count == 1 else {
        return false
    }
    textField.text = formattedString
    currentPosition = getCursorPositionForTextField(string: string, cursorPosition: currentPosition, formattedString: formattedString, textBeforeEditing: textBeforeEditing)
    handleTextFieldCursor(cursorPosition: currentPosition, textField: textField)
    return false
```

So when I type 1234567890, it gets formatted to 1,234,567,890

The issue here is that when I cut any characters from textfield, I am unable to paste it anywhere else. I am unable to detect the reason why it isn't getting pasted. Please could someone help me out.

Is there any way to detect the cut operation for the same? Cut operation is getting overridden by the above code it seems.

Comment: You should be definitely setting `locale` for your formatter.

Comment: @Sulthan No. This is the only code used in the delegate method

Comment: Any locale that doesn't use `.` as decimal separator and `,` as grouping separator will break your code.

Comment: @Sulthan So is it related to cut operation?

Comment: Probably not but pretty dangerous to do.

Comment: Another interesting issue I see is that `NSString.range(of:).location` can return `NSNotFound` and comparing that with a location can result in something unexpected.

Comment: Okay, so please suggest best practice to format textfield while typing, along with allowing cut, copy, paste

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks for the insights and the prompt replies